# What to return from ExecuteAsync for event-driven background tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

As part of my REST API I have a BackgroundService that subscribes to a message queue and waits for particular messages to be received and performs certain actions based on the type of message.

In ExecuteAsync I'm currently returning Task.CompletedTask since I don't have anything to 'await', however I'm thinking this is actually incorrect and could be potentially problematic although I'm not sure what exactly how or what problems could arise as a result.

Would it be acceptable to simply 'await' Task.Delay with an infinite delay? Something like:

```
await Task.Delay(Timeout.infinite, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Just return `Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: Currently I am, however looking at the source code of BackgroundService shown in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice. Specifically the line that checks _executingTask.IsCompleted and takes a different code path which assumes the task is no longer running.

Comment: I must be misreading your question. Is `ExecuteAsync` not your message queue handler? Why isn't the work actually completed by the time you leave the `ExecuteAsync` method? Can you provide more code?

Comment: this depends on the consumer of your `ExecuteAsync`, what if it expects the method to complete but actually the method is never completed? Your scenario is for a background service which ***should not be consumed directly in any code***, the other code should  just ***start*** the service and never wait on that service. The data is transferred via message queue or message bus or event broker ...

Comment: The code inside ExecuteAsync simply subscribes to a message queue, with a callback that is invoked for each message. It isn't an asynchronous API and as such doesn't need to awaited, however ExecuteAsync expects a task returned. This is a completely valid use-case as stated in the article I referenced however there isn't any documentation around what to return.

Comment: Here is a similar use-case, which supports my initial suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196690/what-should-backgroundservice-executeasync-return-when-the-worker-is-event-drive

Comment: This is now starting to stray into Opinion-based
 questioning, which is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Answer (score 4):

## TLDR

Essentially it boils down to: Return `Task.CompleteTask`.

I'd even recommend just using `IHostedService` directly instead of `BackgroundService` because you aren't really gaining anything from what I can see.

## IHostedService

The first thing to look into is `IHostedService`. This interface is what `BackgroundService` implements, and is what enables running code on startup of the host. The interface only adds the `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` methods (no `ExecuteAsync` method).

If we look at the source code for `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` we can see that when we call `AddHostedService` all it's doing is adding the IHostedService to the `IServiceProvider`.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where THostedService : class, IHostedService
{
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, THostedService>());

    return services;
}
```

Then, inside `Host.StartAsync` it does some startup stuff, but the main thing is how it starts the `IHostedService`'s.

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // Omitted for brevity 

    _hostedServices = Services.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();

    foreach (IHostedService hostedService in _hostedServices)
    {
        // Fire IHostedService.Start
        await hostedService.StartAsync(combinedCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (hostedService is BackgroundService backgroundService)
        {
            _ = HandleBackgroundException(backgroundService);
        }
    }

    // Omitted for brevity 
}
```

Why show all this? I think it's important to know there is no real magic happening here. Whenever `StartAsync` on the host is called, all it does is call `StartAsync` on the IHostedServices. Conversely `StopAsync` on the `IHostedService` is only called when `Host.StopAsync` is called.

So what makes BackgroundService special?

## BackgroundService

You might have noticed there is some special code when starting the `IHostedService`'s checking if it's a `BackgroundService`. You have already posted a link to the source for `BackgroundService`, but I'll post the main parts here for visibility.

```
public virtual Task ExecuteTask => _executeTask;
protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Create linked token to allow cancelling executing task from provided token
    _stoppingCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

    // Store the task we're executing
    _executeTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
    if (_executeTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executeTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

As you can see, it's never actually awaiting on the Task returned from `ExecuteAsync`. This is what allows us to have ongoing tasks inside a `BackgroundService`. If you were to try doing a `Task.Delay` with a huge delay inside a normal `IHostedService`, your Host would never start properly.

In the situation that you return `Task.CompleteTask` from `ExecuteAsync`, it'll just return that complete task back to the `StartAsync` from `Host`.

So what's the point of doing all this with `BackgroundTask`'s? Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but from looking at it, it seems like it only really exists for exception handling on long running Tasks. If we look at the `HandleBackgroundException` inside `Host.StartAsync`, we see this:

```
private async Task HandleBackgroundException(BackgroundService backgroundService)
{
    try
    {
        await backgroundService.ExecuteTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.BackgroundServiceFaulted(ex);
    }
}
```

All it does it takes the Task from `ExecuteAsync` and waits it, which allows us to see any exceptions thrown by sending it to the Logger.

## Conclusions

Based on what I saw in the source code, I didn't see anything about your case that warrants a `BackgroundService`.

You've said '*It isn't an asynchronous API and as such doesn't need to awaited*', which to me means you don't gain anything from `BackgroundService`.

You should just use a `IHostedService` and setup your callbacks in `StartAsync`, then remove them in `StopAsync`. There is no reason from what I can see this wouldn't work. It's not like your `IHostedService` is being stopped because it's not 'running' anymore.

If you wanted to stick with a BackgroundService, it's smarter to return `Task.CompleteTask` instead of awaiting a delay. The delay will still use some resources to keep the timer, even if that's small.